# How does checkbox in Filterbar work?

Tags: sapui5

I am using `sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar` (not `sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar`), there are checkboxs in Filter Dialog, when I click it, the filterItem dom will disapear, but I can still get the value in `search` function by `this.getView().byId("thisFilterItemSelectID").getSelectedKey()`, why ?

Can I disable these checkboxs or get the enable state of them so that I can ignore the filter in my `search` function? I've read the `Filterbar/FilterItem` doc and could not find the method/property.

> PS: The user can choose to hide filters on the expanded filter bar by deselecting the relevant checkbox next to the filter in the filter dialog (for example, if a filter is rarely edited, or unimportant).
>   https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/filter-bar/

Comment: When you look at [Sample filter bar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.filterbar.example1/preview)
and click on „Filters“-button to the right, the Filter Dialog opens, where the checkbox for “labelB” in “Basic” is greyed out.
Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew Thx, tried ` mandatory="true"` and the checkbox is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we agree on this answer:
When you look at [Sample: Filter Bar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.filterbar.example1/preview) 
and click on „Filters“-button to the right, the Filter Dialog opens, where the checkbox for “labelB” in “Basic” is greyed out.
Here the checkbox is disabled due to the field being set to “mandatory”.

Comment: One step further, what if this filter is not mandatory ? For `<fb:FilterItem id="directionFilter"`, I tried `getVisible()` and `getVisibleInFilterBar()`, they always returned true whether the checkbox is selected or not; https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterItem.html#getVisibleInFilterBar

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from SAP Fiori Crew, the problem has been solved.

Here is the demo : https://jsfiddle.net/tinachen/ywrxn6ta/

If you switch off the field "LabelA" in FilterDialog, `oFB.determineFilterItemByName("A").getVisibleInFilterBar()` will return `false`, that's exactly what I want.